# Assigning value to Object.values(object)[i] not working

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am saving an object, but later when I add new values it return undefined. I am attempting to set any value that is undefined to the initial value, but unsuccessfully. I have tried assigning it to a fixed value, but it also does not work, and I do not know the cause of the problem.

```
let initalObject = {
   keyOne: true,
   keyTwo: "string",
   keyThree: 0,
}

let object = {
   keyOne: true,
   keyTwo: "string",
}

for (i = 0; i != Object.keys(initalObject).length; i++) {
   if (Object.values(object)[i] == undefined) {
      Object.values(object)[i] = Object.values(initalObject)[i];
   }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't work is that `Object.values(object)` is not `object` itself, but it is an array of values. You need to access the values of `object` directly using its keys.

```js
let initalObject = {
   keyOne: true,
   keyTwo: "string",
   keyThree: 0,
}

let object = {
   keyOne: true,
   keyTwo: "string",
}

const keys = Object.keys(initalObject);
for (key of keys) {
   if (object[key] === undefined) {
      object[key] = initalObject[key];
   }
}

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can achieve the same using a `for in` loop.

```js
let initialObject = {
   keyOne: true,
   keyTwo: "string",
   keyThree: 0,
}

let object = {
   keyOne: true,
   keyTwo: "string",
}

for (let key in initialObject) {
  if (!object[key]) {
    object[key] = initialObject[key]
  }
}

console.log(object)
```